# Definition of probability coupling

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

In my math essay I have defined the probability coupling as follows

$$\Pi(\mu,\nu)=\left\lbrace \pi \in \Omega \left\vert 
\begin{matrix}
\pi(A\times\mathcal{Y})=\mu(A) \\
\pi(\mathcal{X} \times B)=\nu(B)
\end{matrix}\right. \right\rbrace, \quad
 \begin{matrix}
A\subset \mathcal{X} \\
B\subset \mathcal{Y}
\end{matrix}$$

Where $\pi$ is a probability measure, $\Omega$ is the combined probability space and $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ are the probability spaces of measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ respectfully.

Now I got the comment that I cannot use $\pi\in\Omega$ because $\pi$ is a probability measure. My question is that why I cannot use this notation and how should I define the measure $\pi$ so it fits my definition above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\pi$ is a probability measure on $\Omega$, not an element of $\Omega$. The set of probability measures on $\Omega$ is sometimes denoted $\mathcal M_1^+(\Omega)$.

Comment: Ah yes now I get it. Could you explain what the + and 1 in the $\mathcal{M}^+_1(\Omega)$ mean?

Comment: The superscript + stands for the set of nonnegative measures and the subscript 1 for the set of measures of mass 1.

Comment: Can the coupling define on two different spaces $X\times Y$?